# Массив [ [ key1 => value1, key2 => value2 ], ... ] в массив [ value1 => value2, ... ]

Tags: php, yii2

В БД есть таблица (настройки сайта):

```
+----+-------+--------+
| id | name  | value  |
+----+-------+--------+
|  1 | test1 | value1 |
|  2 | test2 | value2 |
+----+-------+--------+
```

Я выбираю строки (работаю с Yii2) и получаю следующий массив:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => test1
            [value] => value1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => test2
            [value] => value2
        )

)
```

Хочу получить следующий (для удобства использования):

```
Array
(
    [test1] => value1
    [test2] => value2
)
```

Я пошёл этим путём:

```
$prettyResult = [];

foreach ($initialResult as $value) {
    $prettyResult[$value['name']] = $value['value'];
}
```

Однако, что-то мне подсказывает, что это как-то топорно и задуманное можно реализовать более элегантно с помощью нативных функций или SQL (или Yii2)?

<s>В последнее время, почти везде, где встречаю перебор массива, это кажется топорным ...</s>

Comment: Короче трех строчек решения скорее всего не будет. Можно сделать через array_combine, два array_map и лямбды, но толку от этого никакого.

Comment: @Etki, нашёлся в одну :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно, Вам поможет функция `array_column()`:

```
array_column($array, 'value', 'name');
```

До:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => test1
            [value] => value1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => test2
            [value] => value2
        )

)
```

После:

```
Array
(
    [test1] => value1
    [test2] => value2
)
```

Проверить можно [тут](https://3v4l.org/gjQBP)

Comment: man: http://php.net/array-column ... блин, смотрел же, но так впадлу было разобраться как она работает ... пускай этот комментарий будет уроком-напоминанием как для меня, так и для тех, кто не читает документацию по функции/методу/etc до конца :)

Comment: Для меня было неожиданно, кстати, что мой первый ответ был для Вас. 
Раньше встречались, но только на другом проекте и помогали Вы мне. Мир тесен, как говорится)

Comment: О, на просторах разработки не раз ещё встретимся, а может и поработаем вместе :)

Comment: Хорошая песочница (не только по PHP): https://repl.it/CuHQ ...

Comment: Оу, спасибо, а то я первую попавшуюся взял

Comment: Но плюс http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com в том, что там можно версии PHP менять.

Answer (score 1):

Вам может помочь метод [`yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper.html#map()-detail).

Сигнатура:

```
public static array map ( $array, $from, $to, $group = null )
```

В качестве `$from`, указываете `name`, а в качестве `$to` — `value`.

---

**Пример:**

```
$array = [
    ['name' => 'test_name_1', 'email' => 'test_email_1'],
    ['name' => 'test_name_2', 'email' => 'test_email_2'],
];

$result = \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($array, 'name', 'email');

echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); echo '</pre>';

// Array
// (
//     [test_name_1] => test_email_1
//     [test_name_2] => test_email_2
// )
```

Comment: Также есть и стандартный метод array_map: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php